# How to display java swing on X11 when running on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, x11

I would really like to be able to run our test suite on Xvfb so that swing windows don't keep popping up in the way of my work. Unfortunately I cannot seem to find a way to get the java runtime to use the display specified in the DISPLAY environment variable. I suppose this is because the Mac JDK is hardwired to use the (non-X-based) Mac display.

I can't find any switches for the java command that say to use X either.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to get Apple's JDK to use X11, but there is the alternative of using [SoyLatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/), which is a Mac Java implementation that only works with X11.

Comment: The official Java runtimes use the platform native GUI API.  Thus the Mac Java runtime, like the MS Windows Java runtime, doesn't support X11.

Comment: Is SoyLatte a good VM, or just a small one-man project? I'd like to run a visual editor on my Ubuntu laptop for editing files on my Mac over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your application from within the X11 terminal. This worked for http://mcis.polymtl.ca/makao.html for me on MacOS 10.14.5

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it, but I am cheating by using Docker.

- Download and install latest docker desktop.
- docker pull [this
  image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk):

docker pull openjdk

- If you want to display on mac, make sure to install XQuartz.
- Ditto: In preferences, security, check both boxes for authentication and allow network
- Ditto from mac or system with xwindows: (you have set DISPLAY environment variable)

  xhost + $DISPLAY
  (on Mac OS X this command will also launch XQuartz)
- Run Java in docker (lots of information on the docker hub web page)

  docker run  -e DISPLAY /bin/bash
  (this line passes the contents of the DISPLAY environment variable)

It is also possible to [install alternate forms of java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536134/install-specific-java-version-for-12-04/536161#536161) into various docker images. In this example you won't be able to display in xwindows unless you additionally :

```
apt-get install  -y libxext-dev libxrender-dev libxtst-dev
```

as part of your "RUN" section in the docker file. using the update-alternatives script does not handle dependencies. I have gotten Java 7 working following those instructions and adding the X libraries.

-