# Java regression testing (with AWT involved) possible without stealing desktop focus?

Tags: java, regression-testing, gui-testing

I've got regression tests of a Java system that don't bring up any graphical elements but do make use of the AWT event thread.  Is there any way I can set things up to run this test suite in the background on my workstation without it constantly grabbing focus from whatever else I'm working on?  (I'm running this on a mac.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your on a Mac:
[Run Tests - Without Focus Loss!](http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/run_tests_without_focus_loss)

Comment: What I wound up with, for now, is like a simplified version of this answer.  I created a second user on the machine, ssh to the new user (who must be logged in via fast-user-switching) and run the tests as the other user in the terminal window.  It works and saves me the thrashing, but there are a lot of little issues, like juggling permissions (I use a lot of chmod -R g+rw .)  I'll post again if we do better.

Answer (score 1):

Try running java with -Djava.awt.headless=true parameter. This should work for you if you are not using any graphical elements.  Hopefully, it will prevent the program from grabbing focus while it is running.

java -Djava.awt.headless=true

Here are some links with more information:

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071208235352641

Comment: The codebase has too many historical dependencies on AWT to do make the necessary refactoring practical.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute these tests with a virtual desktop, virtual machine (like VMWare) or virtual frame buffer. I'm not sure about Mac, but on Linux it works great with `xvfb`.

Comment: This is the first answer I looked into because it seemed the lowest-overhead.  There's an additional stackoverflow thread that makes me think it might not be easy.  Doesn't seem like there's a good way to ask Mac's java to use X11 instead of the native UI components.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897054/how-to-display-java-swing-on-x11-when-running-on-mac